# Query to display rows that have specific values for an attribute in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables prereq and workorder. Prereq has attributes type and status and wonum, workorder has wonum. now I want those wonum's from workorder for which if the prereqs of type ='ABC' or type ='DEF' are present should be in COMP status only.

```
Eg:
Workorder:
wonum
123
456
245

Prereq:
type   status   wonum
ABC     COMP     123
DEF     PENDING  123
TEST    WORKING  123
ABC     COMP     456
TEST    WORKING  456
ABC     COMP     245
DEF     COMP     245
TEST    WORKING  245

Output: 456, 245
```

Explaination: 123 has both prereqs ABC and DEF but DEF is in pending hence I dont want this in result
456 has only ABC in COMP status, so valid result
245 has both prereqs in COMP staus, which again is valid

I tried two logics as below:

First:

```
select * from workorder w inner join prereq p
on w.wonum=p.wonum
where (p.type ='ABC' and status='COMP')
or (p.type='DEF' and status='COMP')
result: this shows 123 as well in output which is incorrect
```

Second:

```
select * from workorder w inner join prereq p
on w.wonum=p.wonum
where (p.type ='ABC' and status='COMP')
AND (p.type='DEF' and status='COMP')
result: this does not show 456 in output which again is incorrect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT wonum
FROM prereq
WHERE type IN ('ABC','DEF')
GROUP BY wonum
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'COMP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Status <> 'COMP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0
```

Not sure that you need the join to `WorkOrder` but it won't hurt anything if you add that back in and alias the columns.

**Edit**

One way to include work orders with no prereqs or prereqs other than ABC, DEF, would be `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT wonum
FROM prereq
WHERE type IN ('ABC','DEF')
GROUP BY wonum
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'COMP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Status <> 'COMP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT wonum
FROM workorder w
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM prereq p
                  WHERE p.wonum = w.wonum
                  AND p.type IN ('ABC','DEF'))
```

The second query will include any work orders that don't exist in the prereq table with `type IN ('ABC','DEF')`.  This will also cover for work orders that don't exist in the prereqs table at all.

Comment: Presumably if a work order has no prerequisites at all, it should be selected. Also, if it has other prerequisites but not 'ABC' or 'DEF', it should be selected. It doesn't look like this query would do what the OP needs.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah it's a little unclear, but I think this solution is in the ballpark.  Those conditions would be simple enough to add if OP clarifies.  As is, the expected output is returned.

Comment: Yes, this solution is working but as mathguy pointed out, if a work order has no prerequisites at all, it should be selected. Also, if it has other prerequisites but not 'ABC' or 'DEF', it should be selected. It would be great if you could add these conditions as well in the answer.
Thanks for the help @AaronDietz

Comment: @vanitajeshnani Thanks for the comment, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
with
workorder (wonum) as (
select 123 from dual union all
select 456 from dual union all
select 245 from dual
),
prereq (typ,   status,   wonum) as (
select 'ABC',     'COMP',     123 from dual union all
select 'DEF',     'PENDING',  123 from dual union all
select 'TEST',    'WORKING',  123 from dual union all
select 'ABC',     'COMP',     456 from dual union all
select 'TEST',    'WORKING',  456 from dual union all
select 'ABC',     'COMP',     245 from dual union all
select 'DEF',     'COMP',     245 from dual union all
select 'TEST',    'WORKING',  245 from dual )
select * from 
(
  select distinct wonum from prereq
  where wonum not in (
    select wonum from prereq
    where typ in ('ABC', 'DEF') and status != 'COMP'
  )
) join workorder using (wonum)
;
```